# Seeking incline of roads data

Tags: data, road, united-kingdom

I need to plot the incline of roads in England. I could estimate this using elevation data, however this would be a significant amount of work.

Does this data already exists (ideally free with a permissive license)?

I've spent this morning googling and haven't been able to find anything, but thought there is a good chance a dataset like this already exists, so thought I should check before embarking on creating it myself.

Comment: http://brouter.de/brouter-web does gradient of roads using OpenStreetMap. Ordnance Survey MasterMap Highways Network is going to be very expensive.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be easy to find the elevation data. After you have found this (as a raster tif file) you can calculate the slopes in for example QGIS. This is done by just clicking a few times so this should be fairly easy.